# Multiple loop in wordpress with post type

Tags: php, wordpress, post, loops

I have this code to display all post:

http://pastie.org/5124323

Shows the two types of post but does not work pagination. When I go to the next page shows the same post in the home page. I do not know what the problem is.

And in the post_type "articles" category are not displayed.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Posting your code/errors as part of your question is likely to garner more responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding pagination parameters to your query:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>array('post','articulos'),  'paged'=> get_query_var( 'paged' ) ));
```

More on pagination parameters here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters